# Python: Convert A string of formula to lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a string of formula lets said:

```
str1='(0.5-0.70*x0[0])**2+(0.5-0.70*x0[1])**2'
```

how can I pass it into lambda function fn Automatically by variable str1

`fn= lambda x0: str1`

---

The goal for this is I would like to get a function object:<function **main**.(x0)>
and finally pass it to scipy.optimize.minimize(fn=fn), if you can solve this directly, you can skip the question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

str1='(0.5-0.70*x0[0])**2+(0.5-0.70*x0[1])**2'

x0 = np.ones(2)

minimize(lambda x0: eval(str1), x0=x0)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but the OP should keep in mind the warnings in [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)